# Swift で Google Maps SDK for iOS を使用して指定座標を取得する方法

Tags: swift, google-maps

Swift で Google Maps SDK for iOS を使用して座標を取得する際、
現在位置は取得できるのですが、
指定した位置の座標を取得する処理がわからず苦慮してます。

GMSMaker を生成する際、draggable プロパティを True にすることで、
ピンを長押しした後、指定座標にドラッグすることができるので、
didEndDraggingMarker イベントで取得できるのかなと思いますが、
実現したい理想の処理としては、
LINE の位置情報送信画面のように、画面中央にピンを配置し、デフォルトでドラッグ状態にすることです。

ご存じの方がおりましたら、何卒お知恵をお貸し頂けますでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mapView.projection.visibleRegion` で、「現在表示している地図領域」が４つ（左下、左上、右下、右上）の緯度経度で取得できます。
この領域の中心が「画面中央」の緯度経度になるでしょう。
(ただし地図をチルト(傾け)させていると、目的とは少し異なる位置になるかもしれません)

- [GMSProjection Class Reference  |  Google Maps SDK for iOS  |  Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_projection)

あるいは、

`projection.pointForCoordinate` で、画面座標を緯度経度に変換できるので、こちらでも代用可能と思います。

Comment: 返信いただきまして、ありがとうございます。
まさに期待していた動作を実現することができました。勉強になりました。